# Python ODBC decimal error

Tags: python, python-2.7, odbc, pyodbc, vertica

I've look for solutions to this error but I'm still striking out. I'm using a python 2.7 venv with pyodbc 3.0.6

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(myconnstring)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT varchar_column, date_column as epoch, decimal_col1, decimal_col2
FROM   table;""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
#do some more stuff down here with rows.
```

Basically it errors out when it's trying to fetch the data from the database in the query specified. I've tried filtering out null results and 0 results, which doesn't help. I've tried casting it to a varchar and using isnull to catch anything that won't have data and nothing seems to be making a difference.

I've tried running the query in the database and it returns fine and if i try to filter for nulls the results are exactly the same so there effectively are no null results. If I filter out 0's there are about 100 less rows but even when I take those out of the script it's still throwing an error which doesn't make sense to me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myodbcscript.py", line 29, in <module>
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
  File "/opt/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 548, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "/opt/python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3866, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: u'1-'
```

As requested in the comments, the DBMS I was trying to connect to was Vertica and the issue wasn't with Vertica itself the queries work fine on there. It was the combination of CentOS 6.4, a python 2.7 venv and Vertica 6.1 driver that resulted in this odd behaviour. As it turns out I was converting my date_column to an epoch and in doing so the result was not being read correctly. It worked fine if it was being returned with only numeric columns but not if I introduced a varchar column.

Comment: Which DBMS are you connecting to?  What if you select just decimal_col1 in your query?  Still error out?  What if you just select decimal_col2?  What if you fetch one row at a time?  Does the error occur on the first fetch or somewhere else?  What does your connection string look like (minus the username and password of course)?

Comment: Ok so I tried doing just the single columns and interestingly it works if I use these 3 together: date_column, decimal_col1, decimal_col2 and it works for each column individually but if i try to select the varchar_column with any of the others i get that error

Comment: actually @StevenRumbalski your method really helped. it's the date_column + varchar_column that were for some reason throwing the error if i used them together. i cast the date_col to a varchar and it works. seems strange but thanks for the ideas!

Comment: It might be helpful for future readers if you would at least indicate the DBMS you are using. I just tried to recreate your issue using Python 2.7.5, pyodbc 3.0.7, and SQL Server Native Client 10.0 on Windows, but your code worked fine for me.

Comment: @GordThompson updated in question.

Comment: Try to cast that decimal to either float or string type and fix this issue on the Python side later. I think that will work, even though it is ugly. Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536059/python-pyodbc-connections-to-ibm-netezza-erroring